# one graph with two diffrent y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to ask you please about how to create one graph with two diffrent y axis?

```
!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np 

df=yf.download('cl=f',start='2019-01-04',end='2021-06-2',interval='1d')

df['LogReturn'] = np.log(df['Close']).diff()
df['volitality']=df['LogReturn'].rolling(3).std()


#I want plot Close price with volitality, but the issu is that volitality y axis is way less than the price 

df[['volitality']].plot(figsize=(10,5));
df['Close'].plot(figsize=(10,5))
```

this has put them into two diffrent graphs. I want to create one graph with two y axis. One that displays the close price and the other for the volatility. Any sugestions?
thanks

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html

Comment: It does not work with dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a dataframe with 2 columns 'a','b'. Each contains 100 random numbers

```
import random

a = [random.randint(-100,100) for _ in range(100)]
b = [random.randint(-100,500) for _ in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns=['a','b'])
```

Next I used the following code for the graph

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax1.plot(df['a'])
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df['b'], color='red')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]